# Hide row div for medium or large screens

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, hiddenfield

i have a site that needs an alternative home page for XS screens. I have hidden the controls on XS screens successfully but am struggling to get a control to show on an XS screen.
I cant see anything regarding visibility on the chrome debugger (f12) but maybe its the order in which i state the bootstrap parameters for showing and hiding a col.

The following simplified code does not show on a XS screen. help!

```
    <div class="row row-top col-xs-12 visible-xs hidden-md hidden-lg">              
                  <a  href="/home.html">test</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, i got it - i need to have 2 divs, one for row class and another for col class. my bad.

```
    <div class="row row-top hidden-md hidden-lg">   
        <div class="col-xs-12">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="/home.html">M.F.O'Hare & Associates</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```